# Conditional radio button in webobjects

Tags: java, html, webobjects

I have following code for the radio buttons:

**Test.html**

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>
         <webobject name=RadioButton1></webobject>  &nbsp;
         <webobject name=LocalString1>A</webobject>
       </td>
       <td>
         <webobject name=RadioButton2></webobject>  &nbsp;
         <webobject name=LocalString2>B</webobject>
       </td>
       <td>
         <webobject name=RadioButton3></webobject>  &nbsp;
         <webobject name=LocalString3>C</webobject>
       </td>    
    </tr>
 </table>
```

**Test.wod**

```
RadioButton1: WORadioButton {
    name = "type";
    selection = requestType;
    value = 0;
}


RadioButton2: WORadioButton {
    name = "type";
    selection = requestType;
    value = 1;
}


RadioButton3: WORadioButton {
    name = "type";
    selection = requestType;
    value = 2;
}
```

I have following webbjects to show : A, B & C

```
<webobject name=A></webobject>

<webobject name=B></webobject>

<webobject name=C></webobject>
```

**Question is:**

I want to show the webobject A when user select the RadioButton1, B when select RadioButton2 & C when select 3.

What condition I apply to the radio button and How ?

Comment: Tad may be correct but I have to clarify. Are you asking how to get the proper thing to show when the user selects one of the radio buttons and hits the form submit button, or do you want something to be revealed to the user when they click on one of the radio buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are not using Project Wonder?

Is sounds like you need an AjaxObserveField to watch the button and fire the update. This requires Wonder!

http://wiki.wocommunity.org/dashboard.action

there are Ajax examples that would really help.

this link may help with installing wonder:

http://wiki.wocommunity.org/display/WEB/Project+Wonder+Installation